# Advice: Mostly custom HTML & CSS with a bit of Content Management

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

Up until now I've been building custom websites, writing HTML, CSS, jQuery from scratch and using plug-ins wherever necessary.

One could consider these websites as static pages, i.e. there's no dynamic content.

Now as one might imagine, ofttimes clients ask for a news section, or a place to upload pictures, etc. In these cases I've been using Wordpress, but have never been overly happy with the results, due to design restrictions posed by the CMS.

So the advice I'm looking for is this:
**What would be a good set-up for coding mostly custom webpages, but having a few pieces of 'dynamic content', editable by the client?**

I.e. have fully static pages save a couple of blocks which would hold dynamic content.

I could see this going two ways: either a CMS that is very 'customization' friendly, or static HTML pages with 'dynamic content' plugged in.

The benefit for the client would be that they'd have the web-design they like and also the ability to log-in somewhere and update or add certain parts of the website.

I could go on and on describing my 'ideal' situation, but I hope the above will be enough for a couple of fruitful answers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am a wordpress fan for CMS usage, have you tried using page templates that pull in dynamic content (a specific post/page in wordpress) and then you can restrict the user/client to be able to edit that 'page' only - allows you to easily handle images etc they may upload via css.. just a thought, sorry but I don't have any massive experience with alternative CMS but that is one way that I have 'managed' this issue in the past

Answer (score 0):

I would go with PHP and SQLite. It wouldn't require additional setup for the client, can be easily moved to other servers and PHP is the most supported language across hosting services.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, CMS is really the only way to go. You could go the route of using something like PHP for example and than creating some kind of admin that will allow the customization of those dynamic areas that you talk about. This would require a custom solution that you would have to roll your own or have someone develop it for you. Almost like static pages with dynamic widgets. Definitely the backend would be an admin area that would allow this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

A CMS can do whatever you want it to, as long as you know the language it's written in. Theoretically you could develop a WordPress theme that is completely static - there wouldn't be much of a point, but it is possible. You just wouldn't add any of the WordPress functions to display any of the content and everything would be hard-coded into the website's files.

If you learn basic WordPress theme development, you can make the website you want and include the WordPress functionality where you want it.

Technically, all a theme needs is `style.css` and `index.php`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates. You can put whatever other files you want, and as long as `style.css` has the information header, it will be a WordPress theme.

Then if the client wants a blog, you can have the client publish posts, and you can add the code to display that feed on whatever page you want.